# Run two webservers with twisted

Tags: python, twisted

I have a task to run a webserver with twisted capable of working with websockets and standard HTTP functionality. Say, I need to use websockets and connect to `hostname:9000`. I need to get webpage and use `hostname:80/webpage` to get it. How I am supposed to do it?

I tried something like:

```
    internet.TCPServer.__init__(self,9000, WebSocketFactory(factory))
    internet.TCPServer.__init__(self,80, server.Site(HandlerHTTP))
```

And it's not working: server on 80 port starts, but one at 9000 doesn't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An instance of `twisted.application.internet.TCPServer` represents *one* TCP server.  You can't initialize it twice and get two servers out of it.

I expect a more complete code snippet than you gave would look like:

```
from twisted.application import internet

class TwoServers(TCPServer):
    def __init__(self):
        internet.TCPServer.__init__(self,9000, WebSocketFactory(factory))
        internet.TCPServer.__init__(self,80, server.Site(HandlerHTTP))
```

This doesn't work.  It's like trying to have an `int` that is two integers or a `list` that is  two sequences.  Instead, make two TCPServer instances:

```
from twisted.application import service, internet

from websocket import WebSocketFactory

factory = ...
HandleHTTP = ...

holdMyServers = service.MultiService()
internet.TCPServer(9000, WebSocketFactory(factory)).setServiceParent(holdMyServers)
internet.TCPServer(80, server.Site(HandlerHTTP).setServiceParent(holdMyServers)

...
```

Comment: Great, that was exactly what I suspected yet your answer gave me a complete understanding. Thanks!